# How to create a TIFF file?

Tags: php, image-processing, tiff

How to create a [TIFF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_Image_File_Format) file in PHP?

I want create a TIFF file and fax it.
I know how to fax it but I don`t know how to create a TIFF file.

Comment: Do you want to create the image or just convert to a TIFF? For the latter compile in ImageMagik.

Comment: I want to create Tiff
if don`t find any solution then create jpeg and convert it to Tiff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [ImageMagick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ImageMagick). Don't count on trying to use the PHP extension for it though, you're going to be making shell commands to the `convert` command.

It's as simple as:

```
system('/path/to/imagemagick/convert orginal_image.jpg new_image.tiff');
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

[ImageMagick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ImageMagick) is the solution.