# Is there any function to create tiff image in php

Tags: php, tiff

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create a TIFF file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951101/how-to-create-a-tiff-file)

```
 imagejpeg($this->image, $dirName . $nameFile . ".jpeg");
 imagepng($this->image, $dirName . $nameFile . ".png");
```

Is there any function to create tiff image in PHP like this?

Comment: Not with GD, no. Can you use [ImageMagick?](http://www.imagemagick.org)

Comment: What about creating jpg from GD and converting it to TIFF, using command line ??

Answer (score 1):

try too look at this with Image Image Magick

http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php?ImageMagick=43mf2hql2g1o4h3f8h1gighr16

i think helpful

Thanks