# Converting a TIFF image to PNG/JPG/GIF in PHP without Imagick

Tags: php, png, jpeg, gif, tiff

I am working on a website for my client in which tiff images need to converted to png or jpg before they are assembled into a PDF.

I have read many articles, here and other sites, on this issue. They all recommend using Imagick to accomplish this. The problem is, my client's server does not have that extension installed, and the hosting company is unwilling to install the extension.

Nor is PDFLib installed on the server (which supports importing tiffs into a PDF).

Thanks.

Comment: EDIT: The PDF generation is working fine. The problem is with the conversion.

Comment: Here is a similar post about creating tiff with PHP http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951101/how-to-create-a-tiff-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is tricky because of the tiff format. You can do this for most input formats with native PHP functions to create an image object from the source file and then save that using imagejpeg or imagepng. But tiff has patent issues and I don't think it's supported. Have a look at the PHP GD and image functions available on your server. May be some help in the comments here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.pdf-open-image-file.php

Comment: Nice answer. It would have worked...but PDFLib isn't installed on the server either.