# Possible to convert TIFF to JPG or PNG without ImageMagick?

Tags: php, image

I'm trying to use PHP to convert base64 TIFFs. The problem is that GD cannot read TIFFs and we don't have access to ImageMagick on our shared hosting. I'm wondering if there's an alternative approach to solving this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting a TIFF image to PNG/JPG/GIF in PHP without Imagick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559370/converting-a-tiff-image-to-png-jpg-gif-in-php-without-imagick)

Comment: Even with the answer @Dagon posted, I hope you're comfortable with the idea you might be processing the image on your own.