# Convert .tif image to jpeg image

Tags: php, image, codeigniter

I have a image format which is in `.tif` i want to convert the image into `.jpeg`.
I tried to remove extension `.tif` and add `.jpg`.But The Image is Crashed.Is there Any way to do this?

I am Using Codeigniter FrameWork .

Comment: [Use gd or imagemagick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14342355/convert-tiff-to-jpg-in-php)

Comment: _“I tried to remove extension `.tif` and add `.jpg`”_ – please tell us you did not actually expect that to work …?

Comment: See the following links.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14342355/convert-tiff-to-jpg-in-php

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559370/converting-a-tiff-image-to-png-jpg-gif-in-php-without-imagick